# How to identify this JavaScript "undefined" console error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, undefined

I could use some help identifying a way to track down this random "undefined" error I am getting in my console. It tells me the violation is in the jquery.validate.unobtrusive but not telling what fails.It is not affecting any functionality from as far as I can tell but I would like to fix it regardless as to not cause future issues when this view is changed and updated which it significantly needs.
I tried to cut down the code below as much as possible.
**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PushToDiamond", "Support", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TransactionView" }))
{
    <input type="submit" form="TransactionView" onclick='return SubmitValues();' class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value='PushToDiamond' />
}
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/SupportScript")
}
```

**JavaScript Function:**

```
function SubmitValues() {
    debugger;
    if ($('input[name="IsSelected"]:checked').length == 0) {
        alert("Please select check boxes to process.");
        return false;
    }
    var i = 0;
    $('input[name="IsSelected"][type="checkbox"]').each(function (e, g) {
        if ($(g).prop('checked')) {
            var c = document.createElement('input');
            $(c).attr({ 'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'PolicyTransactionPKList[' + i + ']', 'value': $(g).val() });
            $('#TransactionView').append(c);
            i++;
        }
    });
    return true;
};
```

**Controller Method:**

```
public ActionResult PushToEmerald(SupportModel model)
{
     _logger.LogInformation("Support - Pushing");
     var env = GetEnv(model?.Country);
     var rq = new PushToEmeraldRq { 
          Environment = env, 
          PolicyTransactionPK = model.PolicyTransactionPK ?? 0, 
          PolicyTransactionPKList = model.PolicyTransactionPKList ?? new List<int>()
     };
     var rs = _policyTransactionService.PushToEmerald(rq);
     model.ProcessRecord = rs.ProcessRecord;
     model.PolicyTransactions = rs.PolicyTransactions;
     return View("Index", model);
}
```

**Ambiguous Console Error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLFormElement.onError (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:41:25)
    at $.validator.proxy (jquery-3.6.0.js:10780:13)
    at $.validator.showLabel (jquery.validate.js:983:35)
    at $.validator.defaultShowErrors (jquery.validate.js:928:11)
    at $.validator.showErrors (jquery.validate.js:553:10)
    at $.validator.form (jquery.validate.js:468:9)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.js:106:20)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.js:5430:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery-3.6.0.js:5234:28)
onError @   jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:41
proxy   @   jquery-3.6.0.js:10780
showLabel   @   jquery.validate.js:983
defaultShowErrors   @   jquery.validate.js:928
showErrors  @   jquery.validate.js:553
form    @   jquery.validate.js:468
(anonymous) @   jquery.validate.js:106
dispatch    @   jquery-3.6.0.js:5430
elemData.handle @   jquery-3.6.0.js:5234
```

**Debugger Console Results:**

```
$("form").serialize()
'Country=Usa&IsAllTransactionsSelected=false&IsSelected=37644306&IsSelected=37647734&Country=Usa'
```

```
$("form").validate()
$.validator {settings: {…}, currentForm: form, labelContainer: jQuery.fn.init(0), errorContext: jQuery.fn.init(1), containers: jQuery.fn.init(0), …}
containers: jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(0)]
currentElements: jQuery.fn.init []
currentForm: form
errorContext: jQuery.fn.init [form]
errorList: []
errorMap: {}
groups: {}
invalid: {}
labelContainer: 
jQuery.fn.init []
pending: {}
pendingRequest: 0
settings: {messages: {…}, groups: {…}, rules: {…}, errorClass: 'input-validation-error', pendingClass: 'pending', …}
submitted: {}
successList: []
toHide: jQuery.fn.init []
toShow: jQuery.fn.init []
valueCache: {}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I have tried adding a debugger into the JavaScript to hit as soon as the button is clicked and testing the form.serialize() and form.validate() commands however they come back successful and as soon as I continue the error persists.
This is the first line from the button click so I am kind of lost.
I have tried VS Debugging and nothing is caught. I have tried breakpoints on the controller but that is kind of irrelevant considering the error posts to the console before the controller is called.

Comment: Check everywhere you have a JSON.parse in your code and put a console.log of the string you're trying to parse before each one of then check the logs during runtime.

Alternatively you can add debugger statements before the parsing as well and check the current state of the variables before the error occurs

Comment: can you create fiddle for your issue? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: JSON.Parse is only used in the jquery package and a single script that is not used here. I have checked that.